# Git: Prevent extern user's from accessing specific branches

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

I have to deal with the following scenario: Let's say we have a project and we use git for this purpose. Extern users should be available to work on parts of the code (plugins,...) not directly affected by internal changes. Thus, since git is not able to remove read privileges, what do you think about this procedure:

1. Create two repositories repo_int, repo_ext. Repo_ext with only one branch called "shared".
2. Let the extern developer push to that branch
3. Use local clone to pull and push to the second internal developer branch

This could be done as follows:

create bare repositories

```
$ mkdir ~/remotes/repo_int.git
$ cd ~/remotes/repo_int.git && git init --bare
$ mkdir ~/remotes/repo_ext.git
$ cd ~/remotes/repo_ext.git && git init --bare
```

create new locale repository

```
$ cd /path/to/my/project && git init
```

create a shared branch & check out

```
$ git checkout -b shared
```

add remotes repo_ext and repo_int

```
$ git remote add -t shared repo_ext ~/remotes/repo_ext.git 
$ git remote add repo_int ~/remotes/repo_int.git
```

make an initial push

```
$ git remote push repo_ext shared && git remote push repo_int *
```

set HEAD from repo_ext to branch shared

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/shared
```

to gain external access onto repo_ext:

```
$ git clone ~/remotes/repo_ext.git
```

do some changes and push the stuff

```
$ git push origin shared
```

in the internal repository perform a branch checkout and use the changes, e.g. to merge or cherry-pick

```
$ git clone ~/remotes/remote_int
$ git checkout -b shared repo_ext/shared 
...
```

What would you say, is this an recommendable secure way to handle this? I heard about "gerrit", which is a code review tool with a far-reaching user right management. Would it be possible to deal with the problem using this tool?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, take a look at gitolite, there you can fine-tune access for various users and e.g. restrict it to specific branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is built as a decentralized version control system. That means you can easily push and pull commits between different repositories.

Just create a public repository and a private repository, and have the public repository only pull specific branches of the private one. When a commit to one of the public branches is pushed on either repository, you should use a post-receive hook to also push it onto the other.

This is in fact nothing else than you creating local branches on your local repository. You are the only one who can work with your local branches, unless you allow someone to pull them from you.

Comment: what do you exactly mean with this post-receive hooks? One further problem is that server-side bare repositories need local clones to handle pushes. Not that easy :)

Comment: Git supports so-called "hooks" - scripts which are executed when specific events happen. A post-receive hook is one which is executed after a commit was received by the repository. https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html

Comment: I haven't tried, but I think bare repositories are able to pull from each other. I believe that's how the pull requests on GitHub work (which are an entirely server-sided process).

Comment: hmmm ... but how to deal with conflicts in this case?

Comment: When both repositories are bare and commits are exchanged immediately, the two repositories should always have the same state. The only possible scenario where a conflict would be possible, would be when two users push conflicting commits to the two repositories at exactly the same time. When the second user would push just after the repositories synchronized, he would get the "your repository is out of date" error message and would have to pull and resolve the conflict locally.